# What are the Signs that I might get my Italian visa?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I applied for an Italian visa on 3rd April 2019 at VFS global. The embassy called my mom the next day since I am a minor and asked her a few questions like what I am doing right now (my mom told them I am currently waiting to join the university on may. We had provided letter of admission to show I was going to the university since I had just graduated from high school last year). They asked what my sister does in Italy since she's the one inviting me as a birthday present (my birthday is on 28th April 2019). She told them the details that my sister is a business woman. They also asked the name of my sisters son and how old he was and she told them. After all the questions the guy from the embassy she was talking to on phone told her "ok". I am so nervous right now and eager to know the results. Might this be a sign I might get my visa.

Comment: The sign is when you receive an email or a text from VFS Global.

Answer (score 2):

No-one can answer your question with any certainty. It is normal for an Embassy to verify information provided in an application but it doesn’t indicate whether the visa will be approved or refused.